# Segfault while trying to compile R 3.2.1 with ACML math library when using proprietary NVIDIA driver

Tags: r, ubuntu, nvidia, blas

Running Ubuntu 14.04, trying to compile R with the ACML math library, and I get this error:

```
byte-compiling package 'grDevices'

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: solve.default(rgb)

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'
 2: solve(rgb)
 3: drop(whitexyz %*% solve(rgb))
 4: make.rgb(red = c(0.625, 0.34), green = c(0.28, 0.595), blue = c(0.155,     0.07), gamma = 1.8, white = "D65", name = "Apple RGB")
 5: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
 6: eval(exprs[i], envir)
 7: sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source)
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
12: try(sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source))
13: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc, keep.source, partial = TRUE)
14: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
15: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package, lib.loc,     keep.source, partial = TRUE))
16: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     compress = compress)
17: tools:::makeLazyLoading("grDevices")
aborting ...

Traceback:
 1: solve.default(rgb)
 2: solve(rgb)
 3: drop(whitexyz %*% solve(rgb))
 4: make.rgb(red = c(0.625, 0.34), green = c(0.28, 0.595), blue = c(0.155,     0.07), gamma = 1.8, white = "D65", name = "Apple RGB")
 5: eval(expr, envir, enclos)

Traceback:
 1: solve.default(rgb)
 2: solve(rgb)
 3: drop(whitexyz %*% solve(rgb))
 4: make.rgb(red = c(0.625, 0.34), green = c(0.28, 0.595), blue = c(0.155,     0.07), gamma = 1.8, white = "D65", name = "Apple RGB")
 5: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
 6: eval(exprs[i], envir)
 7: sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source)
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "\n  ", condition = e))})
 6: eval(exprs[i], envir)
12: try(sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source))
13:  7: sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source)
 8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
loadNamespace(package, lib.loc, keep.source, partial = TRUE)
11: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)14: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
15: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package, lib.loc,     keep.source, partial = TRUE))
16: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     compress = compress)
17: tools:::makeLazyLoading("grDevices")
    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]aborting ...
        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
12: try(sys.source(codeFile, env, keep.source = keep.source))
13: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc, keep.source, partial = TRUE)
14: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
15: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package, lib.loc,     keep.source, partial = TRUE))
16: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     compress = compress)
17: tools:::makeLazyLoading("grDevices")
aborting ...
/bin/bash: line 8: 54105 Done                    echo "tools:::makeLazyLoading(\"grDevices\")"
     54106 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) | R_COMPILE_PKGS=1 R_COMPILER_SUPPRESS_ALL=1 R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL LC_ALL=C ../../../bin/R --vanilla --slave > /dev/null
```

I configured it with `./configure --with-blas=-lacml_mp --with-lapack --enable-R-shlib`

I am running the proprietary NVIDIA graphics card driver, which seems to be the thing causing the problem, though I have no idea how.  Here are the results of other attempts at compilation:

- Using the open source nouveau driver, it compiles fine just like this (but I need to use the proprietary NVIDIA driver for other reasons)
- If I leave out `--with-blas=-lacml_mp --with-lapack` I can compile fine even with the NVIDIA driver
- The same thing happens with R 3.2.0

Also, `libacml_mp.so` is in the right place, so the problem isn't linking to it -- I can compile and link to it fine with the nouveau driver.

My guess is that this is hopeless, either I have to use the nouveau driver or else I have to find some other BLAS/LAPACK implementation to use.  But if anyone has any idea what's going on here I would be very greatful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ACML libraries are aimed at OpenCL on AMD GPUs, although I am still piecing this together. The whole thing is in flux, and you will see that ACML is now being retired in favour of an open source alternatives. See message at top of http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/archive/amd-core-math-library-acml/ .

As you have an NVIDIA graphics card, you won't have FLGRX installed, which I had thought was a pre-requisite for ACML. Do you have an AMD CPU, and is this why you chose the ACML libraries?

I would recommend not using ACML at all. I also am curious as to why you're compiling R to link directly against the library: it's easier to use the generic interface provided by interface `libblas.so.3`, then you can switch BLAS without recompiling R. That way, you can get your runtime errors more quickly...

ACML has never worked with R for me, and I'm tempted to blame its closed source nature, and multiple FGLRX/ACML/graphics card version hell.